# Extract specific file in .tar.gz using PHP

Tags: php, tar

I have a specific file in a `.tar.gz` archive that I'd like to extract. How do I do this in PHP?

For example, MaxMind's [GeoLite databases](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite2-free-geolocation-data) are available as a `.tar.gz` files. For each product, the filename is `GeoLite2-ProductName.tar.gz`, inside there's a `GeoLite2-ProductName_yyymmdd` directory, and inside that, a `GeoLite2-ProductName.mmdb` file along with a few other text files. I only want to extract the `.mmdb file`.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP [phar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php), open the `.tar.gz` archive, iterate through the files, and extract only the filename you're interested in.

```php
$phar = new \PharData('/var/www/html/GeoLite2-ProductName.tar.gz');

foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($phar) as $file) {
    if (str_ends_with($file, 'GeoLite2-ProductName.mmdb')) {
        $contents = file_get_contents($file->getPathName());
        file_put_contents('/var/www/html/GeoLite2-ProductName.mmdb', $contents);
        break;
    }
}
```